# Using firebase different apps same project vs different projects

Tags: android, firebase

I'm an android developper and i've a few apps published on google play... I do myself every single aspect of my apps including maintence.

I've two similar apps that share some core API... they dont share database nor storage, just some java API of my own and some google cloud functions i made (public)

When i was preparing the firebase infrastructue to run the second one i decided for creating a second app in the same firebase project as the first one... this was a decision made basically because i hated the firebase "switch between projects" tools.

my question is:

what are the advantages and disadvntages of having multiple apps sharing same firebase project?
when should i create a new project for a new app and when should i reuse the project

I'm a single self suficient developper so any sort of "project permissions" wont make difference to me

Answer (score 2):

The primary reason to have multiple apps in the same project is when you want to share database and user data between them.  Multiple apps in the same project are definitely expected to share data and configuration across all Firebase products.  A common use case is when you have an end-user app and an admin app, both working against the same data.

If you're not sharing data between the apps, then you will only run into future trouble if you have multiple apps in the same project.  (For example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61668088/807126) which was asked at the same time as yours.)

Comment: firebase team should really put some effort into making switch between projects more usable

Comment: You are encouraged to send your feedback to Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: So if I have two apps - a buyer app and a seller app, but the backend is my own, I just use Firebase for FCM and Auth, do you believe I should make two separate projects or different apps in the same project?

Comment: @Yogesch Also interested for an answer to your question. Would you mind creating a new SO question just for this? Thanks!

Comment: I am now using two separate projects. For easier separation of concerns.